# Making subtitles (.srt) bigger or smaller with mpv

Tags: mpv

How do I make subtitle appear larger or smaller with mpv ? The subtitles are in .srt format most of the times but sometimes also in the movie itself ?

Is there a way to do that ?

Also is there a default configuration variable that I could put so that subtitles play uniformly, using my own fonts and weights etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [Manual](https://mpv.io/manual/master/) has an [entire section about subtitles](https://mpv.io/manual/master/#subtitles).

2 relevant options:

- [`--sub-scale=<0-100>`](https://mpv.io/manual/master/#options-sub-scale)  just scale them
- [`--sub-ass-force-style=<[Style.]Param=Value[,...]>`](https://mpv.io/manual/master/#options-sub-ass-force-style) Force specific style.

Add these to `~/.mpv/config` by removing the leading double-dashees (`--`).

All of that only works for non-image based subtitle formats

Edit: @cipricus points out, that you can set shortcuts for increasing/decreasing subtitle size and position in the file `~/.config/mpv/input.conf`

Answer (score 32):

You can also add shortcuts to `~/.config/mpv/input.conf`  to adjust the subtitles size as you want.

```
# increase subtitle font size
ALT+k add sub-scale +0.1

# decrease subtitle font size
ALT+j add sub-scale -0.1
```

Note: if the config file doesn't exist, just create it in that location

Comment: I guess you can so same with parameter sub-font-size as docs say this parameter is preferred (see other answer).

Comment: **This is the best answer.** `--sub-scale` affects both ASS and non-styled subtitle formats. `--sub-font-size` only affects non-styled subtitle formats. Therefore it's best to adjust the scale factor to ensure that the shortcut works even for ASS subtitles.

Answer (score 16):

The default shortcuts for adjusting subtitle font size:

<kbd>shitft</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd> : to increase font size

<kbd>shitft</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> : to decrease font size

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

Inspired by the other answer - namely this: https://mpv.io/manual/master/#options-sub-scale, where what it says is:

> --sub-scale=<0-100> Factor for the text subtitle font size (default: 1).
>
> Note
>
> This affects ASS subtitles as well, and may lead to incorrect subtitle
>   rendering. Use with care, or use --sub-font-size instead.

Therefore, looking up `--sub-font-size`, we see this:

> --sub-font-size= Specify the sub font size.
>   The unit is the size in scaled pixels at a window height of 720. The
>   actual pixel size is scaled with the window height: if the window
>   height is larger or smaller than 720, the actual size of the text
>   increases or decreases as well. Default: 55.

So - create the file `config` in a folder `~/.mpv` with a line like

```
sub-font-size=44
```

to get 80% of the 55 default size.

Log out and back to see changes.

Comment: The option exists, but its value is [0..1], not [0..100]. For example: 0.5 is a correct value.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @Fayçal answer you can adjust scale on the fly *after* playing media. using tilde keyboard shortcut (without holding shift, it's actually backquote) it'll go to the command mode, then you can do the following:

```
add sub-scale +0.1
add sub-scale -0.1
```