# sub-scale=1 doesn't work in ~/.mpv/config

Tags: shell, configuration, video, video-subtitles, mpv

I am running mpv on Debian testing/buster hence running mpv 0.25.0 . I had asked a question about making subtitles bigger in [Making subtitles (.srt) bigger or smaller with mpv](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/362828/making-subtitles-srt-bigger-or-smaller-with-mpv) and was told that if I put the values in ~/.mpv/config it should work .

I put the following values -

```
[$] cat config                                                                                                                     
     1  # Write your default config options here!
     2  alang=eng,en,english
     3  slang=en,eng,english
     4  sub-scale=1
```

and tried to source it and got the following error -

```
[$] source ~/.mpv/config                                                                                                           
/home/shirish/.mpv/config:4: command not found: sub-scale=1
```

Can somebody tell/share what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Is your config really in $HOME/.mpv/config?   Mine is in $HOME/.config/mpv/config (Jessie).  mpv is working with profiles. `mpv --profile=help` will show the existing.   `mpv --show-profile=profilename`  shows option from profile.

Comment: `└─[$] pwd                                                                                                                            
/home/shirish/.mpv` Should it be somewhere else. `┌─[shirish@debian] - [~/.mpv] - [10028]
└─[$] ll -h                                                                                                                          [20:47:56]
total 8.0K
-rw-r--r-- 1 shirish shirish   96 2017-07-09 23:41 config
drwx------ 2 shirish shirish 4.0K 2015-01-01 17:44 watch_later`

watch_later is a directory dunno for what.

Comment: `[$] mpv --profile=help                                                                                                             
(null) requires an argument
Available profiles:
 opengl-hq 
 encoding 
 libmpv 
 builtin-pseudo-gui 
 pseudo-gui 
 default`

Comment: Can you make a chat open?  I need more Information.

Comment: not atm, guess it needs more questions and answers for the chat thing to come on-board, ask your query. As and stack gives me the option, will open it.

Comment: When you will the option for DVD write in your config `[protocol.dvd]
profile-desc="Profil für dvd:// Streams"
alang=en
slang=en
sub-scale=5`  start playing DVD `mpv dvd://` This works for me, but in Jessie

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62111/discussion-between-shirish-and-bahamut).